# How to get response code in backbone js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I get Response code in backbone js when i fetch the result using fetch() method of collection?
I know it executes error callback function when the response code is like 4xx and success callback method when the Response code is like 2xx.

```
var x = user.fetch({
    error:   function(model, xhr, options){
       alert('Error on fetch')
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    },
    success: function(model, response, options) {
        alert(user.toJSON());
    }
```

Here I want to get Response code, No matter whether It is an error callback or success callback.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What are you getting from your alerts/console.log commands here?

Comment: Thanks Lix for your quick reply..


In case of error console.log(xhr.responseText);
displays error message, I had set server side in response object.



And In case of success console.log(user.toJSON()); displays data available in Model.

Answer (score 4):

If you want response code get it like this:
-In case of success,

```
console.log("Response code in case of success:",options.xhr.status);
```

-In case of error,

```
console.log("Response code in case of  failure",xhr.status);
```

Comment: Thanks pan. That's what I was searching for. It works perfectly.